# don't know how to build task "db:rollback"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I am using `rake 0.8.7` and `rails 1.2.3` now. And when I want to do some db migration stuff using `rake`, it shows no complain when I type in "rake db:migrate". But when I use "rake db:rollback", it gives messages:

`don't know how to build task "db:rollback"`

Actually, all other commands except "migrate" do not work on my machine. such as `rake db:migrate:up` or `rake db:version`, they all give "don't know how to build task" error.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you using Rails 1.2.3?

Comment: Yes, we are maintaining a very old and huge project.

Answer (score 1):

That's a newer rake command.  With your old version of rake, you'll have to do `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=xxxx`

Comment: Like I said, all other commands fail. For `db:migrate:down VERSION=XXX`, it also gives "don't know how to build task" error.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your Rakefile to include:

```
namespace :db do
  desc 'Rolls the schema back to the previous version. Specify the number of steps with STEP=n'
  task :rollback => :environment do
    step = ENV['STEP'] ? ENV['STEP'].to_i : 1
    version = ActiveRecord::Migrator.current_version - step
    ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate('db/migrate/', version)
  end
end
```

Some project templates leave the rollback task out of Rakefile, which is dumb.